# Proper way of POSTing JSON Formdata

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express

I wonder what the correct way of submitting a form is when the serverside expects JSON. The server is implemented in node.js using the express framework. To parse the request body the bodyparser.json() middleware is used.

Currently I intercept the submit using JavaScript and then create an object of the formdata that is in turn POSTed using ajax.

My problem with this implementation is that the response of the POST is a whole page that the user should be redirected to. I thought of replacing the HTML content of the page with the content of the response but that seems pretty dirty to me and also leaves the browsers URL untouched.

TL;DR: How to submit a form so that it is accessible via req.body.myObj in express and the browser is redirected to the response?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Why not just post `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data instead, which is what most servers will expect, including node's bodyparser ?

Comment: I like the way how the submitted form becomes available in req.body.whatever without any hassle if it's submitted in JSON. Maybe I'll just switch to req.param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported way for a form to submit a JSON formatted request. (For an unsupported way, see [W3C HTML JSON form submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/)).

The only way to do it is to use Ajax. You can then either modify the DOM based on the response (normal Ajax) or make a GET request by setting `location` (and passing data in a session / through the URL / etc (which is rather a hack)).

The best approach is generally to reserve end points that expect JSON requests for HTTP APIs and to write end points that expect form url encoded or multipart data when you want to handle a regular form submission.

```
// Don't do this
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

// Do this most of the time
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

// Do this if you have file inputs
app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data
```

Code from [the express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body).